# Not unique table/alias - MySQL Join error

Tags: mysql, join, alias

This is from the Northwind database:

```
select `order details`.ProductID,
`Order details`.`UnitPrice`,
`Orders`.`orderdate`,
`Orders`.`RequiredDate`
from `order details`
inner join
`order details` on `order details`.`OrderID` = `order details`.`OrderID`
```

> My error is: #1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'order details'

Where do I need to add an alias? Is it because there are two order details after the join?

Comment: See how easier it would be to read if the table and column names did not have spaces in them?

Comment: I assume you are trying to JOIN the `orders` table with the `\`order details\`` tables but that not what you wrote :)

Comment: same error when replacing with orders instead of order details

Comment: `inner join \`orders\` on \`order details\`.\`OrderID\` = \`orders\`.\`OrderID\``

Comment: Also `Order details` is not the same as `order details`. Table names are case sensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are joining the same table: `"order details"` with `"order details"` instead `"orders"`

In any case I prefer and I suggest everytime use aliases and table names without space. But is a pattern to me, just a suggestion :D

Comment: Its a typo, we dont normally answer typo's we close then as a typo. They are almost never any use to others and thats the prime function of a SO question

Comment: Same error when change to orders

Comment: @CodyRaspien has the table Order the column OrderID ? Can you show us the tables?

Comment: @RiggsFolly oh sorry! I knew it but I thought the error is not clear and others can search in google or SO by the error instead the typo.

Comment: Yes, both have OrderID as int(11)

Comment: @CodyRaspien can you update the question in order to show us the new query? And a table diagram will be nice